# express is not loading static folder with docker

Tags: docker, express

I'm running webpack client side and express for server with docker the server will run fine but express won't load the static files

**folder structure**

```
client
 docker
  Dockerfile
 src
  css
  js
 public


server
 docker
  Dockerfile
 src
  views
```

**client dockerfile**

```
FROM node:19-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

**Server dockerfile**

```
FROM node:19-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

**docker compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api:
    image: server
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

  client:
    image: client
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

**express**

```
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import express from 'express'

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))

const app = express()
const port = 8081

// view engine
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.locals.basedir = app.get('views')

// Middlewares
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/public/')))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/home')
})

app.listen(port)
```

the closest thing that comes to my mind is that the public folder is not being copied by docker since this folder will be generated once i run the webpack server, or what might be causing this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is going to be that you are not adding the folder `/client/public` to the server docker container.

Because of your folder structure, you could add the following line to `server/dockerfile`

```
copy ../../client/public ./client/public
```

then you would need to update your path statement in `express.js`

```js
let p = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../client/public/');
if(!fs.existsSync(p)){
  p = path.resolve(__dirname, './client/public/');
}

app.use(express.static(p))
```

---

The other option you have is to copy the whole project into both docker files and set the CWD, however, this method is not preferred. For example your server file would become

```
FROM node:19-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN curl -f https://get.pnpm.io/v6.16.js | node - add --global pnpm

COPY  package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY ../../ ./

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server/src

EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

---

You can also inspect the file / folder structure by using [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)